# How can i identify the type of noise present in the images

Tags: image-processing, noise

I am presently working with noise removal in images. If the only available information in hand is the noise affected gray scale image, how can I identify what type of noise (say, Gaussian, Poisson, speckle, uniform etc.) is present in the image? What may be the parameters that I can consider to identify the type of noise? I am using gray scale images.

Comment: +1 for a wonderful question. You should try analyzing your images in the Fourier Domain. Convert your images using FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) and study the pattern produced in the frequency domain. Modify the pattern and convert it back to original form using inverse FFT. You can use OpenCV in this aspect

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea. I tried plotting the power spectrum but I didn't know how to analyse it. Is there any specific procedure to analyse the frequency domain pattern? How can I manually or automatically modify the pattern?

Comment: I read that FFT can be useful in the case of periodic noises. Is it possible for me to use the same in case of aperiodic noises like speckle noise, Salt and pepper noise etc.?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to analyze histograms of manually selected image fragments that are known to be homogeneous. Which fragments to consider depends of course on the nature of your images.

Comment: I thought that i can use statistical parameters like mean, variance, SD, skew, kurtosis etc to identify the type of noise. Is it possible?

Comment: I would say that statistical parameters you mentioned can be used to identify parameters of the noise. In order to estimate the type I would examine the histogram of an area that is known to be homogeneous. For example, your images contain background areas that you know should be white. So ideally, if there is no noise present, variation of grayscale values would be minimal in that area. However if the image is corrupted with Gaussian noise the histogram of the background fragment would be like a bell. This is my idea.

Comment: @Flower after giving much thought and having some discussion with some friends at work Sergii's idea is also possible a good solution to start off with. +1 Sergii

Comment: Thank you so much. I will start trying this.

Comment: Does anyone know the range of these parameters for different noises? Is there any literature regarding the range?

Comment: There are two ways of finding the skewness and kurtosis in matlab. One is taking directly from image using functions and the other is finding them from the image's histogram. Which of these two will be more accurate? Or what is the difference between these two procedures?